# Aeson merge object encodings

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I want to parse and write JSON objects that have some base attributes in common and some additional individual attributes. For example, let's say we have two types of objects `User` and `Email`. Both types share the same base attributes `foo` and `bar`, but they have additional attributes specific to their type:

```
User:
{"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar", "user": "me", "age": "42"}

Email:
{"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar", "email": "me@example.com"}
```

I have written `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances for the separate objects `User`, `Email`, and `Base`. Now my idea was to define a wrapper object combining `Base` and any other type with `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances.

```
data Wrapper a = Wrapper Base a

instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Wrapper a) where
  parseJSON = withObject "Wrapper" $ \v -> Wrapper <$> parseJSON (Object v) <*> parseJSON (Object v)

instance ToJSON a => ToJSON (Wrapper a) where
  toJSON (Wrapper base a) = Object (toObject "base" (toJSON base) <> toObject "custom" (toJSON a))
    where
      toObject :: Text -> Value -> KeyMap Value
      toObject _ (Object v) = v
      toObject key v = KeyMap.singleton (Key.fromText key) v

  toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions
```

The `FromJSON` implementations seems to work just fine. Also the `toJSON` function appears to pack all attributes into a single object. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution to merge the two `Encoding`s together. The default `toEncoding` implementation packs the base and custom attributes in two separate JSON objects and merging the underlaying `Builder` with `unsafeToEncoding` doesn't help either.

Is there any `aeson` functionality I am missing completely or is there a much easier approach to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Update**

Thanks to Daniel Wagner's answer I defined to a new typeclass `ToObject` and made the Wrapper data type a little more generic.

```
newtype Merged a b = Merged (a, b)
  deriving stock (Show, Generic)
  deriving newtype (Eq)

class ToObject a where
  toObject :: a -> Object
  toSeries :: a -> Series

instance (ToObject a, ToObject b) => ToObject (Merged a b) where
  toObject (Merged (a, b)) = toObject a <> toObject b
  toSeries (Merged (a, b)) = toSeries a <> toSeries b

instance (FromJSON a, FromJSON b) => FromJSON (Merged a b) where
  parseJSON = Json.withObject "Merged" $ \v -> fmap Merged ((,) <$> parseJSON (Object v) <*> parseJSON (Object v))

instance (ToObject a, ToObject b) => ToJSON (Merged a b) where
  toJSON = Object . toObject
  toEncoding = Json.pairs . toSeries
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build what you need using [`pairs` and `pair`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.1.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Encoding.html#v:pairs).

```
class ToObject a where toObject :: a -> Series

instance ToObject Base where
    toObject b = "foo" .= foo b <> "bar" .= bar b -- but no Ken, how sad
instance ToObject User where
    toObject u = "user" .= user u <> "age" .= age u
instance ToObject a => ToObject (Wrapper a) where
    toObject (Wrapper base a) = toObject base <> toObject a

instance (ToObject a, ToJSON a) => ToJSON (Wrapper a) where
    toJSON = -- as before
    toEncoding = pairs . toObject
```